# How to create versions of projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, version-control

Just a quick, short question: I would like to find a way to create "versions" of the projects that I am working on so that I may make changes and revert back to older versions of the projects if those changes are unsatisfactory. Is there a way to do this inside of Eclipse IDE or must I download an addon of sorts?

Comment: In general: use a software repository, everything else is limited. In specific to eclipse: wrong place to ask here, head over to the SuperUser place, you will find the link at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 1):

As it's been said you need to use some version control software like Git or SVN. They let you to have different branches for the different versions. I'd recommend you Git, as long is more modern and flexible. There are thousands of tutorials over there.

Eclipse has built-in support for Git. If you choose SVN you'll have to install the subclipse plug-in.